# Cron daily running twice

Tags: cron, centos7, cron.daily

On my CentOS 7 server, errors generated by a nightly backup script that should have run fine caused me to check on my cron activity. I discovered that `cron.daily` is running twice - here is the relevant section of `/var/log/cron` after I removed my backup script to see if it was somehow causing the problem:

```
Oct 10 02:28:01 mail CROND[1750]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 10 02:28:01 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[1750]: starting 0anacron
Oct 10 02:28:01 mail anacron[1759]: Anacron started on 2017-10-10
Oct 10 02:28:01 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[1761]: finished 0anacron
Oct 10 02:28:01 mail anacron[1759]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Oct 10 02:30:01 mail CROND[1766]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 02:40:01 mail CROND[1847]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 02:50:01 mail CROND[1936]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 03:00:01 mail CROND[2032]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 03:10:01 mail CROND[2148]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 03:17:01 mail CROND[2223]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.daily)
Oct 10 03:17:01 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2223]: starting kizunademo
Oct 10 03:17:02 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2259]: finished kizunademo
Oct 10 03:17:02 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2223]: starting logrotate
Oct 10 03:17:02 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2266]: finished logrotate
Oct 10 03:17:02 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2223]: starting man-db.cron
Oct 10 03:17:02 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2277]: finished man-db.cron
Oct 10 03:20:01 mail CROND[2288]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail CROND[2367]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2367]: starting 0anacron
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail anacron[2376]: Anacron started on 2017-10-10
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2378]: finished 0anacron
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail anacron[2376]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 35 min.
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail anacron[2376]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Oct 10 03:30:01 mail CROND[2381]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 03:40:01 mail CROND[2462]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 03:50:02 mail CROND[2547]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 04:00:01 mail CROND[2670]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Oct 10 04:03:01 mail anacron[2376]: Job `cron.daily' started
Oct 10 04:03:01 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2685]: starting kizunademo
Oct 10 04:03:02 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2721]: finished kizunademo
Oct 10 04:03:02 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2685]: starting logrotate
Oct 10 04:03:02 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2728]: finished logrotate
Oct 10 04:03:02 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2685]: starting man-db.cron
Oct 10 04:03:03 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[2739]: finished man-db.cron
Oct 10 04:03:03 mail anacron[2376]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Oct 10 04:03:03 mail anacron[2376]: Normal exit (1 job run)
```

Why is `cron.daily` running twice? As you can see, the log contains some entries related to the second run that aren't present for the first run: two lines announcing the upcoming run, and two more lines saying that it terminated with a normal exit. The first run simply ran the scripts with no extra fanfare. I assume that means something, but I don't know what.

I checked everything I could think of for doubles of something. I'm pretty sure I've read every similar thread on the subject, so compare with the following before calling this a duplicate question. Based on [Why is cron running twice?](https://serverfault.com/questions/579479/why-is-cron-running-twice) I checked for extra processes - the complete output of `ps aux | grep cron` is as follows, so there is only one process:

```
root      9383  0.0  0.2 112672  2340 pts/0    S+   15:18   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
root     25624  0.0  0.0 126248   320 ?        Ss   Sep30   0:02 /usr/sbin/crond -n
```

Based on [Cron jobs running twice - Ubuntu server 12.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/461730/cron-jobs-running-twice-ubuntu-server-12-04) I also checked `crontab -l -u root`, which said `no crontab for root`.

And here is my /etc/crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=my@email.com

28 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
17 3 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
44 2 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
8 2 7 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Thoughts?

#### EDIT (9 months after this discussion had fallen silent):

Comment today from Marin Velikov made me aware that there is an `anacrontab` file (I know it's silly, but it hadn't even occurred to me). Here is its contents:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       25      cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45     cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

So that's the cause. *But why would the system be configured to run both?* I assume someone smarter than me set it up this way, so I hesitate to muck with it before knowing the purpose. And if I should indeed get rid of the entries in either `crontab` or `anacrontab`, which one is best? Anacron is apparently the more sophisticated tool, but it seems weird/wrong to empty one's `crontab`. Am I just too old-school?

Comment: Look at file: /etc/anacrontab and see what jobs runs

Comment: @MarinVelikov It sounds silly now, but I didn't even realize such a file existed! I asked in a comment about somehow disabling anacron, but nobody responded (perhaps because I had accepted an answer). Thanks - I edited the question with the new information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is cron.daily running twice?

`crond` is running it once:

```
Oct 10 03:17:01 mail CROND[2223]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.daily)
```

`anacron` is running it once:

```
Oct 10 04:03:01 mail anacron[2376]: Job `cron.daily' started
```

`crond` started `anacron`, that is why you didn't see a process for it:

```
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail CROND[2367]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2367]: starting 0anacron
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail anacron[2376]: Anacron started on 2017-10-10
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2378]: finished 0anacron
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail anacron[2376]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 35 min.
Oct 10 03:28:01 mail anacron[2376]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
```

Comment: Oh, `anacron` is new to me - my old server (CentOS 5) didn't have it. So I thought it was just some part of `cron`, but I've read more about it now. According to tutorials, each distro is supposed to have a way of keeping the two from clashing, but apparently CentOS 7 (or just my server) isn't doing that correctly for daily and weekly. This is a Linode server that should always be running, and it's not the end of the world if a cycle gets missed, so should I just disable `anacron` somehow?

Comment: I went ahead and accepted this as the answer because it did answer what I *literally* asked (why is it running twice). But implicitly I thought I was also inquiring what to do about it - further thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this same situation on one of our servers.  According to the guy I talked to, anacron is meant more for individual PCs that might be powered down overnight, rather than servers that are theoretically running 24/7; anacron looks for jobs that might have been missed while a machine was powered down.  The machine I found this on was a 24/7 type server, and the /etc/anacrontab file was just (re)running cron.daily, cron.weekly, and cron.monthly. I removed anacron from the server I found was doing this, and hopefully this will resolve it.